# Executing two tasks consecutively

Tags: java, multithreading

There's a thread pool with a single thread that is used to perform tasks submitted by multiple threads. The task is actually comprised of two parts - `perform` with meaningful result and `cleanup` that takes quite some time but returns no meaningful result. At the moment (obviously incorrect) implementation looks something like this. Is there an elegant way to ensure that another `perform` task will be executed only after previous `cleanup` task?

```
public class Main {
    private static class Worker {
        int perform() {
            return 1;
        }

        void cleanup() {
        }
    }

    private static void perform() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        Worker w = new Worker();
        Future f = pool.submit(() -> w.perform());
        pool.submit(w::cleanup);
        int x = (int) f.get();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be the case if you submit them in a correct way? E.g., perform, cleanup, perform, cleanup.

Comment: why not just `pool.submit(() -> { w.cleanup(); return w.perform(); });`

Comment: @СӏаџԁеМаятіи That may unnecessarily delay `perform()`. Imagine that `cleanup()` takes a minute and `perform()` takes a second and we submit a task every two minutes.

Comment: But your pool has only one thread.They won't run concurrently. So that's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an elegant way to ensure that another perform task will be executed only after previous cleanup task?

The most obvious thing to do is to call `cleanup()` from `perform()` but I assume there is a reason why you aren't doing that.

You say that your solution is currently "obviously incorrect".  Why?  Because of race conditions?  Then you could add a `synchronized` block:

```
synchronized (pool) {
    Future f = pool.submit(() -> w.perform());
    pool.submit(w::cleanup);
}
```

That would ensure that the `cleanup()` would come immediately after a `perform()`.  If you are worried about the performance hit with the `synchronized`, don't be.

Another solution might be to use the [`ExecutorCompletionService` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) although I'm not sure how that would help with one thread.  I've used it before when I had cleanup tasks running in another thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java8, you can do this with `CompletableFuture`

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> w.perform(), pool)
    .thenApplyAsync(() -> w.cleanup(), pool)
    .join();
```

Comment: Are you sure that no tasks will be executed between perform and cleanup in this case?